# Should I reverse the play button in Arabic?

Tags: video

Should the play button be presented in reverse in Arabic languages?
To be clear I mean the tip of the triangle pointing left

Comment: No, it should not.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

According to [Google Material Design standards](https://m2.material.io/design/usability/bidirectionality.html#mirroring-elements), anything depicting the passage of time should be mirrored. Media controls, however, reflect the direction of a tape being played, not the passage of time. Although their example doesn't show a Play button, the standard is to keep media controls unmirrored.

[image: SCreenshot of Google's LTR media playback controls]

Here's [another article](https://webkul.design/blog/rtl-theme-development/) that shows RTL development with a right-facing Play button.

> The control button for media like video does not require any changes.
> Ex. the play, pause and the seek buttons will remain the same as in
> the LTR

.

[image: RTL media controls]